# xPath select attribute based on other attribute's value

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm struggling with xPath for a while now and i thought i'd got the hang of it until now.

The strange thing is that if i test my pattern [online](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) it works, but when i run it locally it doesn't

I have the following XML

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <Property Title="Toy" Text="Car" />
    </Product>
</Products>
```

Now i want to replace all `Car` values with `Bal` so i came up with something like this:

```
$xml_src = 'feed.xml';
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($xml_src);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach($xpath->evaluate('//Property[@Title="Toy"]/@Text') as $text){
        $text->data = str_replace('Car', 'Bal', $text->data);
}
echo $document->saveXml();
```

But that doesn't do anything (i just get the whole feed with the original values), while the xPath pattern works on the site i mentioned above. I don't have a clue why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to manuipulate the DOM, not just the representation, which in this case means using [DOMElement::setAttribute](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php)

```
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//Property[@Title="Toy"]') as $elProperty) {
    $elProperty->setAttribute(
        'Text',
        str_replace(
            'Car',
            'Bal',
            $elProperty->getAttribute('Text')
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: The OP just used the wrong property. You can fetch and manipulate attribute nodes.

Comment: It's confirmed :-) and the answer works. It's just that if you're thinking in nodes (not just elements) you can get a lot more from Xpath and DOM.

Comment: Got to learn something new every day. php_dom really propagates the change back to libxml.

Answer (score 1):

Your Xpath expression returns `DOMAttr` nodes. You will have to manipulate the `$value` property.

```
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//Property[@Title="Toy"]/@Text') as $text) {
   $text->value = str_replace('Car', 'Bal', $text->value);
}
echo $document->saveXml();
```

A `DOMAttr` has a single child node that is a `DOMText` representing its value, but I don't think it is possible to address it with Xpath. Text nodes would be instances of `DOMText`, they would have a `$data` property.